# Single instance of a class in javascript

Tags: javascript, oop

Javascript allows defining a function as

```
function Name() { content; }
```

and

```
var Name = function() { content; }
```

Is there an equivalent for classes? I'm looking to create a single instance of a class. The only way I know how to do that is

```
function ClassName() { content};
var instance = new ClassName();
```

Can I not combine those two into a single statement?

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You don't have to use a function at all to create the object, if you just want a singleton:

```
var instance = {
    name: "foo",
    method: function() {
        // do something
    }
};
```

That creates an object with `name` and `method` properties. You don't have to add them via initialization like that if you don't want to, you can do this:

```
var instance = {};
instance.name = "foo";
instance.method = function() {
    // do something
};
```

I usually use a function when defining either a singleton or a "class" (really, a constructor function), but that's because I have a thing about *named* functions (the function above that I assign to the `method` property is *anonymous*, which means my tools can't help me much — with call stacks, etc.). So I would probably do this:

```
var instance = (function() {
    var publicSymbols = {};

    publicSymbols.name = "foo";

    publicSymbols.method = instance_method;
    function instance_method() {
        // do something
    }

    return publicSymbols;
})();
```

...although I usually use a shorter name for `publicSymbols` (wanted to be fairly clear what it did). For one thing, that lets me have truly private functions that the singleton or "class" can use that no one else can see. [More here.](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2010/03/anonymouses-anonymous.html) But that's a style choice; it can be as simple as the first two examples above.

Comment: This works! Though I think I'll stick with the `function` method of defining a class for the sake of the syntax.

Comment: @Mikhail: Fair 'nuff. Note that JavaScript doesn't have classes, it just has constructor functions. It's a distinction that does make a difference when you get into how you handle deriving, etc. If you like the "class" metaphor (I do, too), you may find this useful: [Simple, Efficient Supercalls in JavaScript](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2009/09/simple-efficient-supercalls-in.html). It's a mechanism for making it easy to create "classes" and subclasses, etc., with the ability to call into superclass methods.

Comment: @TJ, wow. upvote for the Nifty Snippets link. It's always sad and heart-warming at the same time to see someone develop a syntactically pleasant wrapper for something that I've been hand-hacking for years

Answer (score 0):

you can use this. it is a self executing function that will assign the results of the function instead.

```
var instance = (function className() { return something; } )();
```